# Where is wordpress search page content generated?

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm trying to style a search page in wordpress. In search.php I can style most of the page but then the following statement (which I got from the original uneditted page) generates the content.

```
                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This ALMOST displays the page as I want it, but there are a few elements off the page, making it expand etc. I can't figure out what file is generating this content!

Using the instructions I created a content-search.php and change the line of code to this...

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

Which works...but it doesn't display much of anything because I don't know what to put in my page within seeing the original.

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a template part named `post-search.php` and can use it inside your search.php file like

```
get_template_part( 'post' , 'search')
```

but you have to create a php file inside your theme folder and name it `post-search.php` and inside this file just put the WordPress' loop i.e.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post-entry clearfix"> <!-- Main wrapper -->
    <div class="post-entry-content"> <!-- Post-entry-content -->
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="post-entry-date">Posted on <?php the_time('F Y') ?> with <?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></div>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" class="post-entry-read-more" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read More ?</a>
    </div><!-- END of post-entry-content -->
</div><!--End of main wrapper -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and your search.php could be something like this

```
<?php get_header(' '); ?>
<div id="post-wrap">  
    <div id="post-content"> 
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'post' , 'search') ?> // This will load/include the file post-search.php and result will be displayed as formatted in this file
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>Sorry, it does not exist !</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- END post-conten -->
<?php get_sidebar(' '); ?>      
    </div><!-- END post-wrap -->        
<?php get_footer(' '); ?>
```

This is just an example, change div/h2 id/class names according to your theme css.

**Note:** I'm currently using this approach in one of my site and I've one file named 'post-entry.php' in my theme folder and in my every template file (index.php, search.php e.t.c) I just use this file by calling

```
<?php get_template_part( 'post' , 'entry') ?>
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, this solved it. Only different thing I've done is use content-search.php, but it does the same thing :) Now I know where everything is coming from I can make it look pretty :P